# Maven generates archetype only for Java EE 6

Tags: maven, java-ee-7

How can I "force" maven to generate archetypes for Java EE 7? It only generates for "6". I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS, java jdk 7. I go with "maven archetype:generate", then filter with "jboss".

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the CodeHaus Java EE 7 archetypes. E.g.

```
mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee7 archetype:generate
```

Comment: It successfully generates project, but produces error when compiling.

Comment: What was the command you used to compile and what is the error message? The skeleton app that I just generated was capable of being packaged and run.